# Proper way of storing Playwright element for parent

Tags: playwright

Im trying to figure out the best way to store an element locator to eventually use that locator to find the parent.

For example, in this particular problem I have a table row (`<tr>`), which has a unique text on it `Foo` (as a `<label>`). This table row also has a checkbox. Looks basically like this:

[image: Table Row]

(Pretend there is an outline, but that's essentially the table row layout. The table has a lot of rows (Undetermined amount) so I cannot just say `nth` row. So the obvious unique element is to grab the element via it's text and store the "child" locator. Which i've done like this:

`const tableRow = page.locator('label:has-text("Foo")')`

However now I need to grab the parent of it, that is a `<tr`> so I can then grab the checkbox to click on.

What is the best way about this? Playwright doesn't exactly have a "parent" selector, the closest I could find is the https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-locator-option-has `has` option.

So from my understanding I would need to do something like:

```
  const tableRow = await page.locator('tr', { has: page.locator('label:has-text("Foo")') })
  await tableRow.locator('input[type="checkbox"]').check()
```

Or is there a better way?

As a sidenote: When storing a locator, it says the `await` keyword is not needed (The 1st row of code above). Don't we need `await` when storing a locator?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLb50jwp/ (Obviously the simplest version of it)

Comment: If you share a [mcve] of your website/markup and runnable code, it's much easier to provide a better solution. That said, your second solution looks reasonable--get the row that has that label, and you have both parent and child. Start from the top of the tree and work down, not bottom up. Locators are lazily evaluated, so you only need `await` when you take an action, like `.click()` or `.check()`.

Comment: @ggorlen I added a simple jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks, but can you put the code in the question? External links disappear over time and we have snippets that run the code.

Comment: The code in the fiddle looks weird--usually, labels are connected to inputs so that if you click on the label, it lets you change the connected input. In your case, you have one label `Foo` that's not connected to anything and another label that does wrap an input, but has no text and therefore does nothing as well. You may have oversimplified the code.

Comment: The answer below does show how to get the parent (‘..’), but do you need to get it with the parent? I would actually recommend the `has` approach, as not only is it more semantically getting the row based off the label, as you wanted, but if an extra div is thrown in there or something it would still work. Relative selectors like direct parent or child (instead of ancestor/descendant) are generally very brittle and not resilient to dev changes.

Comment: @DavidR, Did you see my very first answer???, It is not brittle, it's direct to checkbox without parent  and very flexible as it's not absolute locator.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I did, and yes that is true, so that is a good solution. One potential issue is that it will find rows with that text anywhere in it, instead of just the label, but that might not matter for their case since that’s all they have. And generally, my recommendation would be to have the locators be more how the user would locate or other practices or semantic structure Playwright provides, rather than xpath, such as `has`. That being said though, your top answer definitely follows the same vein of flexible and not absolute idea like you said, and is a solid xpath selector/approach.

Comment: Also, based off them saying that they wanted to use the locator for the child to then locate the parent, if that’s truly/specifically what they want to do, `has` as they asked in that case seemed like the most fitting solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How about this direct flexible locator to checkbox as an simple answer:

```
const expectedName="Foo"    
const locator = `//tr[contains(.,${expectedName})]//input[@type="checkbox"]`
```

#### Playwright way to get [parent](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/other-locators#parent-element-locator) locator:

```
parent_locator = page.get_by_role("button").locator('..')
```

The parent element could be selected with .., which is a short form for xpath=..

#### General [Xpath](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) way to get parent locator:

```
Xpath=//*[@id='rt-feature']//parent::div
```

#### To get Parent with specific class:

```
//span/parent::div[@class="parent"]
```

-- returns parent element only of exact node type.

#### Why await keyword is required in general?

[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is usually used to unwrap [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) by passing a Promise as the expression. Using await pauses the execution of its surrounding async function until the promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected). When execution resumes, the value of the await expression becomes that of the fulfilled promise.

#### Why await keyword is NOT required while declaring [playwright](https://playwright.dev/) locator?

At the time of declaring [locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locating-elements) there is no [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) to be resolved so await keyword not required however while performing an operation like 'click' promise is returned from playwright for which await keyword is required to pause the execution until promise is resolved.